# JavaScript Image from random Object?

Tags: javascript, image, random

I have a Button when pressed should: Randomly present Text Information about 3 Objects.

Now I have added String: 'Photo'  to each Object, that holds the photo fileName of it.

Now I have problem with assigning the filename in my random Function correctly.

The target for the Photo is: 'pic'

Im not sure if this is valid:

```
chatObj.photo[randomImageIndex]
```

relative from where my script is located the path to the images is:

```
"../images"
```

Im not sure if this is correct:

```
"<img alt=\"\" src=\"/../images" + chatObj.photo[randomImageIndex] + "\" />"


var Dog = Object.spawn(Creature, {
  type: "DOG",
  legs: 4,
  age: 6,
  name: "Charlie",
  funx: "Run in a circle",
  photo: "dog.jpg",
});



function qRandom(){
    var chatObj = new Array();
    chatObj[0] = obj1;
    chatObj[1] = obj2;
    chatObj[2] = obj3;
    var randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);

  document.getElementById('pic').innerHTML = "<img alt=\"\" src=\"/../images" + chatObj.photo[randomImageIndex] + "\" />"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *each object* has a `Photo` field, then you need to look up the random object *first* and then get its string field, like so:

```
chatObj[randomImageIndex].photo
```

rather than the other way round as you do above.

(Also, I would change the name of the array so that it sounds plural, something like `chatObjs` or `chatObjArray` etc.  At the moment `chatObj` sounds to me like a single chat object, so it feels strange to look up a particular index.)